# Homomorphism between two free abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have two free abelian groups, one generated by a set $X$, the other by a set $Y$. Suppose that $f$ is a group homomorphism between these groups. Does it necessarily map $X$ to a subset of $Y$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$No. Just consider two copies of $\Z$, with $X = Y = \{1\}$, and the homomorphism $n \mapsto -n$.

Answer (score 3):

No, consider the example $$f\colon\mathbb{Z}\langle a\rangle \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\langle b\rangle$$ given by $f(a)=-b$. Here $A\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ refers to the free abelian group $A$ freely generated by the set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$.